# How to make a Cassandra connection

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

i  want to do a connection with Cassandra with java class.But its not working .Here is my code ..

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Row;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;


class CassandraConnection { 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String serverIp = "166.78.10.41";
    String keyspace = "gamma";
    CassandraConnection connection;

    Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
            .addContactPoints(serverIp)
            .build();

    Session session = cluster.connect(keyspace);


    String cqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM TestCF";
    for (Row row : session.execute(cqlStatement)) {
        System.out.println(row.toString());
    }

}
}
```

this is the error log..

### BUILD FAILURE

Total time: 0.883s
Finished at: Wed Jun 05 15:54:02 IST 2013

### Final Memory: 4M/15M

Failed to execute goal on project CassandraConnection: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany:CassandraConnection:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-parent:jar:1.0.0, org.specs2:scalaz-effect_2.11.0-SNAPSHOT:jar:7.0.1-SNAPSHOT, org.scalaz:scalaz-effect_2.9.3:jar:7.1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-parent:jar:1.0.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

Comment: Mandrek reading the error it looks like it is not able to find com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-parent:jar:1.0.0. Looks like runtime maven dependency. Please check in your local repository if you can see this jar file.

Comment: i see the jar in my dependency list but it shows that the dependency not yet downloaded

Comment: OK so you cannot find the jar in your local repository. Right? Please try to download same explicitly and place it in your local repository. Or you need to check firewall rules so as to enable the download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am not a cassandra expert, but
Just by looking at the error, it seems that maven cannot resolve the `cassandra` related dependencies

SOLUTION:

1. I manually checked the maven repo (`http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2`) casandra dependencies are present, which indicate that you may have problem in connecting the `maven repo` from your machine it could be firewall issue.
2. In case firewall is not allowing you download the file from `maven repo`, download the file manually and install the file manually to your local repo (`http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html`).

Answer (score 1):

To be more specific, enter something like this in the  section of the pom file:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
      <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0-rc2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to above from Sajan it could be possible that the downloaded file in your local repository is corrupt so you can follow step 2 of his suggestions.